# JBO-27513: Header value is not valid. Header: REST-Framework-Version; Value: 5

Tags: java, http-headers, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am building an Oracle ADF application and I need to change "restFrameworkVersion" attribute in my adf-config.xml since I need to return a List in my Programmatic View Object's custom method. I have changed my adf-config as follows:

```
<version name="v1" displayName="1" restFrameworkVersion="5"/>
```

and I have set my Header as follows:

[image]

However, I get a 500 error and the following error. I am not sure what is exactly wrong. My Jdeveloper version is 12.2.1.4.0.

```
<REST> <Unexpected error while processing the request> <Error Type=oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.exception.InvalidHeaderValueException> 
<oracle.adf.model> <RESTHttpRequestExecutor> <execute> <Unexpected error while processing the request> 
oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.exception.InvalidHeaderValueException: JBO-27513: Header value is not valid. Header: REST-Framework-Version; Value: 5
    at oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.http.header.RESTFrameworkVersion.parse(RESTFrameworkVersion.java:36)
    at oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.http.RESTHttpRequestWrapper.getFrameworkVersionFromHeader(RESTHttpRequestWrapper.java:431)
    at oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.http.RESTHttpRequestWrapper.<init>(RESTHttpRequestWrapper.java:104)
    at oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.http.RESTHttpRequestWrapper.<init>(RESTHttpRequestWrapper.java:61)
    at oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.http.RESTHttpRequestExecutor.execute(RESTHttpRequestExecutor.java:84)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.execute(ResourceServlet.java:283)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.doPost(ResourceServlet.java:94)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.service(ResourceServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.wsm.agent.handler.servlet.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:360)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$3.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:172)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:110)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilterInternal(JpsAbsFilter.java:273)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:147)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
<oracle.adf.model> <ADFBindingFilter> <checkSessionCreation> <Detected an HttpSession when running in stateless mode.>
```

What could be the possible solution for this? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What are the allowed framework version you see when you access http://<server:port/contextroot>/rest/latest? <version name="v1" displayName="1" restFrameworkVersion="5"/> the restFrameworkVersion version is the "default" fmkw version i.e server will process request considering fmwk version is 5, if nothing is specified in header. Depending on which version of jdev/adf you are, you have to make sure version 5 is supported/available in adf rest.

Answer (score 1):

Use restFrameworkVersion="4" and see if it resolves your problem. I have been using version 4 and not sure if a later version is available.